# EL parameter not working in primefaces tooltip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I get a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException value="#{col.getValue(row)}": Property 'getValue' not found` on the tooltip line.  The other `#{col.getValue(row)}` in the outputPanel and outputText evaluate just fine, which makes me believe there might be a bug in primefaces.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a workaround?

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" var="row" value="#{myBean.getRows(5)}">
  <p:columns var="col" headerText="#{col.name}" value="#{myBean.columns}">
    <p:outputPanel id="tableColumn">
      #{col.getValue(row)}
    </p:outputPanel>
    <h:outputText value="#{col.getValue(row)}" />
    <p:tooltip for="tableColumn" value="#{col.getValue(row)}" />
  </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Using Tomcat 7.0.39 and Primefaces 3.5

Comment: Have you tried `tooltip` separatly to check if it's working at all in your set up ? Something like `<p:tooltip for="tableColumn" value="some value" />`

Comment: Yup, that works.  And so does `<p:tooltip for="tableColumn" value="#{col.name}">`.  Just not when using a parameter.

Comment: That's strange, in fact ...

Answer (score 1):

Just write `#{col.Value(row)}` or `#{col.value(row)}`